# Identifying whether display is broken or the motherboard

Tags: screen, physical-damage

I assume it is possible to damage the motherboard / chips inside a phone if it falls on the ground. So my questions is, is it possible to confirm what has been damaged during the fall?

I don't want to end up buying a replacement display and then found out the problem is somewhere else.

The phone is JiaYu G3T (a Chinese brand), fell on a ground. I completely disassembled the the phone but I didn't find any damage anywhere, everything looks like new.

Pic 1. This should be black with a green logo, left part of the screen is darker than right

[image: Should be black with]

Pic 2. Again, half of the screen is darker, color problems at the bottom OR sometimes the same as the startup screen - grayscale-kind-of-inverted-colors display

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use ADB to test phone functionality. ADB tool can be obtained from Android SDK. There are a number of test commands which you can use to test your phone. Steps are as follows:

1. cd to your ADB directory.
2. Connect your phone to PC via USB.
3. type the following command:

   'adb devices' (without quotes)

You should see your android listed in the CLI. You can also enter device shell:

```
'adb shell' (without quotes)
```

List SD card contents:

```
'ls -l' (regular unix file navigation commands)
```

If you can access your device shell, it's most likely that your motherboard is working fine. There are several commands to check as well:

```
Sending user touch events to Android:
adb shell input keyevent <event_code>
1 -->  "KEYCODE_MENU" 
2 -->  "KEYCODE_SOFT_RIGHT" 
3 -->  "KEYCODE_HOME" 
4 -->  "KEYCODE_BACK" 
5 -->  "KEYCODE_CALL" 
6 -->  "KEYCODE_ENDCALL" 
7 -->  "KEYCODE_0" 
8 -->  "KEYCODE_1" 
9 -->  "KEYCODE_2" 
10 -->  "KEYCODE_3" 
11 -->  "KEYCODE_4" ..... etc
```

Comment: I don't see what any of the tests you recommend has to do with the display backlight failing and display corruption.